# How to change order of items in popup options window in select directive?

Tags: angularjs

I use angularJS select directive in my project.

Here is example:

Template:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="f.name for f in friends "></select>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.friends =
      [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:0},
       {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:0},
       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:0},
       {name:'AllNames', phone:'5558-55', age:0},
       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:0},
       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:0}];

       $scope.selected = $scope.friends[3];
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/1095/).

```
The  `friends` list is list that I get from database table and it ordered as list above.
```

When I click on the select directive, window options is popup with all options that can be selected.I need to make **AllNames** item to be appeared on the top of the list in options window.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your ng-options to this:

```
ng-options="f.name for f in friends | orderBy: 'age' "
```

**edit**: working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/1092/)

Comment: I need to filter it by name property only.